# Как осуществляется передача в функцию параметром Function Declaration и Function Expression?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. В учебном материале есть такой код:

```js
// Выведет 9:
test(function(num) {
  return num * num;
});

function test(func) {
  console.log(func(3));
}
```

Задание: Переделайте ваш код так, чтобы передаваемая функция была не анонимной, а была определена как Function Declaration с именем func.

Вот моё решение:

```js
test(function func(num) {
  return num ** 2;
});

function test(func) {
  console.log(func(3));
}
```

Правильное ли моё решение?
Если да, то как переделать моё решение в функциональное выражение?

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Не могу разобраться. Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0):

> Вот моё решение

Скорее всего имелось ввиду такое

```js
test(func);

function func(num) {
  return num ** 2;
}

function test(func) {
  console.log(func(3));
}
```

Comment: Как-то не додумался до этого. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```js
function test(func) {
  console.log(func(3));
}

// Функциональное выражение
const func = function (num) {
  return num * num;
}

test(func);
```

Comment: Почему Вы использовали `const`?

Comment: Это пример `Function Expression`. Автор просил как  `Function Declaration`...

Comment: @ksa Внизу его вопроса "как переделать моё решение в функциональное выражение?".

Comment: @andreleroo Что-бы случайно где-то в коде нельзя было переопределить имя функции `func`.